# раздел исключений в PL SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

Как правильно написать запрос исключений

в разделе исключений функции выдать сообщение о количестве записей, в которых данные по столбцу commission_pct не изменены.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE function UpdateCourse (pnumber number := 12) return number
    IS
    c number := 0;
CURSOR occupancy_cur IS
    select employee_id, phone_number from hr.employees where LENGTH(phone_number) <= pnumber;
BEGIN
    FOR occupancy_rec IN occupancy_cur
LOOP
IF c >=1 THEN raise_application_error(-20001,'Salary is high');
else
update EMPLOYEES set COMMISSION_PCT = NULL WHERE EMPLOYEE_ID = occupancy_rec.EMPLOYEE_ID;
 c := c + 1 ;
END IF;
END LOOP;
return c;
exception
 when others then raise;
END UpdateCourse;
```

Comment: Не понятно, что не получается. Разбейте полную задачу на части. Создайте минимальный  пример той части задачи, в которой у вас возникли трудности. Опишите ожидаемый результат.

Comment: @0xdb
Спасибо за отзывчивость. Уже разобрался сам. )

Comment: Тема закрыта. Проблема решена.